# having difficulty echo iframe with advanced custom fields wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

Hi guys this is a pretty dumb question im really bad with php and this is basically not working and outputting the wrong thing can someone please help me.

```
if (get_field("gallery")){
  while (has_sub_field("gallery")){
    if (get_row_layout() == "video"){



    echo '<ul class="bxslider">';
     echo '<li>';
        echo '<iframe src="'.the_sub_field("videos").'" frameborder="0"></iframe>';
     echo '</li>';

    }
```

heres a screenshot of whats happening as you can see the URL is not in the iframe src
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Load `the_sub_field("videos")` into a variable first then include that in the string you want to echo out.

```
$myVar = the_sub_field("videos");
echo '<iframe src="' . $myVar . '"....
```

Of course this will not work if you are not correctly return a string from the_sub_field("videos") so make sure that function actually returns a string.